# Phone not recognized in android debugger

Tags: android

I am trying to run the android debugger on my phone, but the console as well as eclipse plugin reports a ??? in place of the device name.
The attached phone is a sony ericsson xperia mini, running android 2.3 and the computer is running on ubuntu 10.10 .
I have enabled the usb debugging option on the phone.

Comment: Have you installed device driver?

Comment: Make sure that you have installed google-usb-driver for that device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter the Phone USB configuration for your device in the udev file on ubuntu

You need to add a **udev rules file** that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the ATTR{idVendor} property. For a list of vendor IDs, see USB Vendor IDs, below. To set up device detection on Ubuntu Linux:

Log in as root and create this file: **/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules**.

Use this format to add each vendor to the file:

```
 SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

In this example, the vendor ID is for HTC. The MODE assignment specifies read/write permissions, and GROUP defines which Unix group owns the device node.
Note: The rule syntax may vary slightly depending on your environment. Consult the udev documentation for your system as needed. For an overview of rule syntax, see this guide to writing udev rules.
Now execute:

```
 chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Vendor ID for Sony Ericcson is

```
 Sony Ericsson  0FCE
```